Problem with getting info from qrcode scanner via UART on python
I have qr and bar Code Reader GM875. I connected it to raspberry pi 4 model b via uart, and wrote python code to get result, but it don't work correctly. from my script i get wrong data bytes like this:
Barcode Data: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...'
Barcode Data: b'\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\x00\x00\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\x00\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xe0\x00\xe0\xe0\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xe0\xe0\xe0\x00\x00\xe0...'
Barcode Data: b'\xf8x\x00x\x80x\x00\xf8x\x80xxx\x80\x80x\x00\xf8x\x80x\xf8\x80\x80\xf8\x00xx\x80\x00x\xf8x\x80\x80xx\x80\x80x\x80xx\x80\x00\x80xxx\x80x\x00xx\x80x\x80xxxxx\xf8xxxxx\x80xx\x80x\x80\x80\x80\x00xxx\x80xxx\x00xx\x80\xf8x\xf8\x80x\xf8xxxx\x80x\x00x\x80x\x00x\x00x\xf8\x80\xf8\x00x\x00x\xf8\x00x\xf8xx\x80\x80x\x80\x80\x80xx\x80\xf8\xf8x\x80x\x00x\x00\x80xx\x80\x80\x80\x00\xf8x\xf8x\x80x\x00x\xf8xx\x80x\x80xxx\x80xx\x80x\xf8x\x80x\x00xxx\xf8x\x80\xf8xxx\xf8x\xf8x\xf8\x80x\x80x\x00'
Barcode Data: b'\xa5\xacj\x85\xd1\xb3\xe6]\xa6/\x92\x85\xae%J\x95\x91\xa4N\xd6I\xe1\xaf\x14\x89\x8a\x12\xe9\xa49\x14\xa5\x95\xa8\xd5\xe9\xa7v\x99\xb7L5\xe9\xb0\x8e\xb2M\xb7\xf6e\xb9&\x97+\x91\xb6\xa5\x8a\xa9\xa1\xba\x16\x95\xf9\xa9\xd5ku\x9d\xe3'      

But after few scanning i getting correct data:
Barcode Data: b'zcYlSQRlS3C/Fz0jIN+LVSTdre/ux/QJN9FjdeDPvMhPyrGdcF7cQczp99f+wfG1Y2tlsDvxYJ/jHzgQqniVnw==\n'

and after this correct data recognition script stops with this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/qrcode_project/qrcode_rpi/t1.py", line 24, in <module>
        read_from_scanner()
      File "/home/pi/qrcode_project/qrcode_rpi/t1.py", line 13, in read_from_scanner
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 549, in in_waiting
        s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

It is not a problem with reader, it works correctly with ESP32, but has this problem with raspberry and python. I also allowed uart on RPI
This is the simplest code i use:
import serial

# Configure the serial connection (adjust parameters as needed)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/serial0',  # Use /dev/serial0 for the Raspberry Pi UART
    baudrate=9600,        # Adjust baudrate to match your barcode reader's settings
    timeout=1             # Timeout in seconds for read operations
)

def read_from_scanner():
    try:
        while True:
            if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                # Read data from the barcode scanner
                data = ser.readline()
                if data:
                    print(f"Barcode Data: {data}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program interrupted. Closing..")
    finally:
        ser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_from_scanner()

I tried to write code on C++, but it also shows wrong data like python code

Also i get this error
File "/home/pi/qrcode_project/qrcode_rpi/t1.py", line 24, in 
read_from_scanner()
File "/home/pi/qrcode_project/qrcode_rpi/t1.py", line 13, in read_from_scanner
if ser.in_waiting > 0:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 549, in in_waiting
s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

That error message suggests that it is an issue down at the hardware or driver level. With the "wrong data" your seeing, it might suggest that you don't have exclusive control of the UART. Have you disabled serial console in raspi-config?  You might be able to get more debug information after seeing that error by running the sudo dmesg Linux command to display the kernel logs. Check whether there is any recent mention of serial or uart, or any other errors that seem relevant.

@ukBaz
thank you very much, it helped

If you have worked out how to fix this then please answer your own question so others can learn.

The answer was to disable serial console, but enable harware serial port with raspi-config

This doesn't actually answer the question. Please edit the answer to give more specifics of what was actually done to get it working
